# How to dynamically show how many mysql queries have been executed on a page?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP page that could potentially result in a lot of mySQL queries depending on what the user searches. For searches that will take a long time, I want to show the user that something is happening, so they don't think the page is broken or hanging. I can't make a progress bar because I do not know how many queries will be executed every time. It depends on the search. I was thinking of having a number on the side of the page that would correspond to the number of queries and this number would increase continuously until the search is over.

This is how I am executing my queries.

```
$query = "SELECT name, id, direct_owner FROM $table WHERE parent_id = '$ownerID'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
```

I am submitting a form for each search and then I use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])
```

Comment: How do you execute your queries? Do you use PDO, a custom class or something else? Please provide more information.

Comment: If you use AJAX to run your queries that shouldn't be too bad. However if you're using a POST or GET method into a PHP page this will prove difficult since you'll have to reload the page when you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server-side, it will not be able to show anything in realtime, you'd need client-side like `Javascript` or `Angular` or `Jquery` for any frameworks.

I "lied" a bit, you can do real-time, but it's very hackish. You can read about `flush()` [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-implicit-flush.php). I wouldn't recommend it, and regardless, you can't do a progress bar with just PHP.

What you should do is create this PHP file as a `postRequest` type and query it using `AJAX`, which is capable of doing live-output and a progress bar. There are multiple libraries out there to help you.

Comment: Will this slow down my actual php script significantly?